# How to prevent pulumi from stripping newlines from output?

Tags: pulumi

I am using the Typescript API of pulumi. I noticed that when I invoke `console.log("\n\n")`, pulumi strips out the newlines. I want to keep these newlines to improve the readability of the deployment log.

Is there a way to instruct pulumi to keep newlines in the output log?

Answer (score 2):

The current behavior of the Pulumi CLI is to break your messages into lines (split by `\n`), trim every line, drop empty lines, and display the result.

Although ugly, you could force your line breaks with an extra "zero-width space" character:

```js
console.log("Top line");
console.log("\u200B\n\u200B\n\u200B");
console.log("There will be three empty lines before this line");
```

You could use something more trivial like `_` instead of the zero-width space. Obviously, underscores will be visible.

Track [this issue](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/3180) for further progress.

Answer (score 1):

Pulumi should not be stripping newlines or otherwise manipulating your `console.log()` output. I just tested this and my string with newlines was printed as expected with newlines.

Code

```js
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

const bucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("main", {
    acl: "private",
})

bucket.onObjectCreated("logger", new aws.lambda.CallbackFunction<aws.s3.BucketEvent, void>("loggerFn", {
    memorySize: 128,
    callback: (e) => {
        for (const rec of e.Records || []) {
            const [buck, key] = [rec.s3.bucket.name, rec.s3.object.key];
            console.log(`Object created: ${buck}/${key}`);
        }
    },
}));

console.log(`My 
multi-line
string`);

export const bucketName = bucket.bucket;
```

Output

```
$ pulumi up -y
Previewing update (dev):

     Type                                  Name                        Plan       Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                   demo-aws-ts-serverless-dev  create     3 ...
 +   └─ aws:lambda:Function                loggerFn                    create

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (demo-aws-ts-serverless-dev):
    My
    multi-line
    string

Resources:
    + 8 to create

Updating (dev):

     Type                                  Name                        Status      Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                   demo-aws-ts-serverless-dev  created     ...
 +   └─ aws:lambda:Function                loggerFn                    created

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (demo-aws-ts-serverless-dev):
    My
    multi-line
    string

Outputs:
    bucketName: "main-b568df3"

Resources:
    + 8 created

...
```

Comment: It seems my question was not clear enough. I want to add empty lines in the output. Your example works because every line contains some text. However, the following will not work: `console.log("first"); console.log("\n\n\n\n\n"); console.log("second");` I am expecting multiple newlines between `first` and `second`. In actuality, I get no space between the two lines.

Comment: Yes, that's different than what I tried. I've opened https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/3180 to address this.